# How do I restrict a user to a specific thin client?

Tags: lightdm, vnc, xdmcp

I am using 10 thin clients on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with an xdmcp server.

All thin clients display all user names and allow any client login with any user account. Even two or more thin clients login with same user.

My problem is to allow only a specific thin client with a specific user. How do I configure this?